# android - detect low network signal, which value to rely on

Tags: java, android, networking, device, dbm

I want to detect a situation where the user is somewhere with low reception (low network signal) for an amount of time (5 minutes for example), and I am wondering what value to rely on.

What I have now is:

```
public class RadiationTest {
    TelephonyManager TelephonManager;
    SignalStrengthListener signallistener;
    private Context context;

    public RadiationTest(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        try {
            signallistener = new SignalStrengthListener();
            TelephonManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            TelephonManager.listen(signallistener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    class SignalStrengthListener extends PhoneStateListener {

        @Override
        public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(android.telephony.SignalStrength signalStrength) {
            super.onSignalStrengthsChanged(signalStrength);
            int SignalStrength_ASU = signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength();
            int SignalStrength_dBm = (2 * SignalStrength_ASU) - 113; // -> dBm

            // here I can use dbm
            // I can also get the bars with signalStrength.getLevel()
        }

    }
}
```

Looking at the dbm values - it seems that its **85** most of the time - which means good reception, and when going to a place with low reception, its getting **negative values**. from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31869981/1662033) answer I learned that negative values for dbm means that the reception is low - but its not negative, it just means your device is very sensitive. (see table in answer).

Also, the dbm values seem to change from device to device.

Looking at the `signalStrength.getLevel()`, it gives you how many reception bars are there, and it looks like a good option.

With that in mind, `SignalStrength` is a class with a lot of values, and I was just wondering what is the most reliable way to test for **low signal** for **some amount of time** and to see if people have some experience with this.

Answer (score 0):

Try Level of Wifi and Cell(mobile data)Net
https://gist.github.com/XinyueZ/fe5f86734730a25638665ad77819d4f8

Level is often being defined from 0 - 3 (max) `getCellStrengthLevel(max: Int = 3)`